# Bindparam Tag - Exclusive to PDO?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Is/should the [bindparam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bindparam) tag be exclusive to PDO and a separate [bind-param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bind-param) tag created for mysqli binding questions?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bindparam/info

The mysqli questions are usually pretty similar; perhaps make an alias to this for a [bind-param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bind-param) tag and expand the info to include mysqli syntax?

Comment: In my opinion, these tags might be overly specific, and questions about parameterized queries in PHP could just be tagged [tag:php] [tag:parameterized-query]. If we create 2 tags with really similar names, there might be confusion.